# Why couldn't wizards in the Harry Potter world create Muggle money and use it to buy gold?

Tags: harry-potter, money

It is well established that [gold cannot be cloned](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59278/why-cant-you-just-duplicate-money-in-the-harry-potter-series) (or transfigurated) permanently and that Goblins can easily detect all forms of counterfeit money. However, it seems that nothing would stop a wizard from transfiguring a bunch of 100 dollar notes and using them to buy a few gold bars. Goblins don't seem to mind "Muggle" gold and it's not like they could tell it was obtained illegally.

So, is there anything in the Harry Potter books or films which mentions why wizards couldn't do this?

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Improper_Use_of_Magic_Office

Comment: "There is legislation about what you can conjure and what you can't." –JKR. These books are written for ---kids--- mass-consumption. Do you really expect JKR to start talking about fiduciaries in them?

Comment: @Valorum it's illegal to duplicate gold, but plenty of people still try (and fail to fool the Goblins).

Comment: The dupe suggests that it's illegal. Given the the consequences of crime in the wizarding world seem to be imprisonment **and torture**, that would act as a strong deterrent.

Comment: If you buy gold with what is later discovered to be counterfeit money, the authorities and such will come for you.

Comment: @Valorum - concur.

Comment: I've closed the question as a duplicate as the answers to the linked question address it. However, it's a good question and I'd encourage you to ask more.

Comment: Also, if you haven't already read it, Harry Potter and the Methods of Rationality (an awesome not-really-fanfic) addresses this in an interesting way, as it does most issues in Potterverse.

Comment: @DVK-in-exile I've read HPMOR, but it didn't deal with this particular idea.

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer - Ron states food is one of the 5 exceptions to Gamp's Law of Elemental Transfiguration while in ROR during DH. To my knowledge the other 4 aren't known. Muggle Money could be one of them.

It's an answer which logically would make sense and doesn't contradict anything from the book, but also one which I doubt is the true reason it doesn't happen.

Comment: see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24803/what-are-the-other-four-exceptions-to-gamps-law-of-elemental-transfiguration